# How do I get AWS CloudFront site to resolve publicly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

**Context:**

1. Created S3 bucket [used example.com, not www.example.com for S3 bucket name][image] have permissions set as shown in screenshot. [image]
2. Certificates [applied]. Please see the screenshot [image: Cert Manager] [certs applied to Route 53. Please see the screenshot [image]
3. CloudFront [please see config screenshot [image: ] Added a subdomain here enter image description here]4. Route 53 [configured, please let me know if there are screenshots that would help]
   **Observed Results:**
4. I can navigate to the "Distribution Domain Name URL" provided in CloudFront's CDN dashboard https://Redacted-Guid.cloudfront.net/ - site resolves fine
5. I get the following https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#CNAME/ response and can navigate and resolve the record returned. https://Redacted-Guid.cloudfront.net.
6. When I navigate to https://www."example".com, I get the following certificate warnings (please see screenshots).[image: Cert CTA][image: Cert CTA2] If I accept the cert, then I get the following 403 error; please see screenshot[image] #3.[image]

**Expected Results:**
The user can navigate to the domain name and see the site via HTTPS connection without 403 error and having to accept a cert.

**Note** Please bear with me if there is latency between your answer(s) and my reading them - I've been heads down in this (when the grass was supposed to have been cut by me), and if I don't cut the grass I'm going to be in a doghouse.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) as alternate domain in your cloudfront definition (plus a valid certificate to prove you own this domain)

Comment: Hi @MarcC - I'm confused, that certificate is in there - it is the only certificate in CloudFront.

Comment: Check the alternate domain name section right on top of the certificate section in the cloufront distribution form

Comment: I'm unable to add a screenshot in this interface after the question is posted, but when I navigate to CloudFront, Distributions, that distribution, I see under custom domains, alternate domains and www.n(redacted).com. Of note, I don't have a cert applied for n(redacted).com (with no www)

Comment: Ok then my answer is not relevant sorry

Comment: Oh no, thanks @MarcC for that, and my fault for not adding that screenshot in there to begin with.